# How to group gwt composite widgets change events as one change event

Tags: gwt

If i have a GWT composite widget with three text boxes like for SSN, and i need to fire change event only when focus is lost from the widget as a whole, not from individual text boxes how to go about doing that?

Answer (score 1):

If you want just the event when your whole widget loses focus (not the text boxes), then make the top level of your widget be a FocusPanel, and expose the events that it gives you.

Comment: That's the first thing i tried but for some reason no events are fired.
FocusPanel holds a HorizontalPanel which has Three text boxes.

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement the Observer Pattern on your composite, and trigger a new notification everytime:

- the focus is lost on a specific text box AND
- the focus was not transferred to any of the other text boxes.

Comment: that won't work because of no guarantee on the order of events of focus lost and focus gained on different boxes.

Comment: Using DeferredCommand might do the trick:
http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/1.6/com/google/gwt/user/client/DeferredCommand.html

Comment: Clarifying: 1. Catch the event of focus lost from one of the text boxes; 2. Use DefferredCommand to check if the focus was not gained on the other text boxes; 3. If the other text boxes didn't gained focus, then your composite fires a "focus lost" (or whatever) notification

Comment: That won't work again, because in the deferred command you cannot be sure which text boxes deferred command in the focus gained method gets called first.

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't you use a timer? On lost focus from a text box, start a 5ms (or something small) timer that when it hits, will check focus on all 3 TextBox instances. If none have focus, then you manually notify your observers. If one has focus, do nothing.

Put this in your Composite class:

```
private Map<Widget, Boolean> m_hasFocus = new HashMap<Widget, Boolean>();
```

And then add this to each one of your TextBox instances:

```
new FocusListener() {
  public void onFocus(Widget sender) {
    m_hasFocus.put(sender, Boolean.TRUE);
  }

  public void onLostFocus(Widget sender) {
    m_hasFocus.put(sender, Boolean.FALSE);
    new Timer() {
      public void run() {
        for (Boolean bool : m_hasFocus.values()) {
          if (bool) { return; }
        }
        notifyObservers();
      }
    };
  }
};
```